# Devices on primary WiFi router not visible to devices connected to the secondary router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

To start with, I am not a networking person and hence my troubles with my network.  Recently I have miraculously managed to install a second WiFi router at home.  I have managed therefore to achieve more wireless connectivity to the internet from all areas at home.  However, the devices that are connected to the original WiFi router are not visible to the devices that are connected to the second WiFi router.  And this is a problem because to the first WiFi router I have a network printer installed with a scanner as well, and also a network access storage hard disk.

The WiFi setup is as follows:

Primary router

- The ADSL modem is connected to the primary WiFi router via the WAN port.
- The NAS and the Printer are connected to this primary router in a wired fashion
- This primary router is set with DHCP on
- This WiFi router has a different SSID than the one given to the second router
- The IP address of the primary router is 192.168.0.1 - D-LINK
- The default gateway is 192.168.1.254 (the IP of the ADSL modem)
- The DHCP IP Address Range is 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.199

Secondary router

- This secondary router has a different SSID than the primary router
- The WAN port of this router is not in use
- This secondary router is linked to the primary router in a wired fashion where the cat5 cable is going into one of the 4 LAN ports and not in the WAN port
- The IP Address of this router happens to be also 192.168.1.254 because it is an MSI.  This IP is therefore equal to the IP Address of the ADSL modem but this did not interfere with the ability to distribute internet successfully from both wireless router.
- DHCP is disabled on this second router

Given all these features, when I connect a laptop to the primary router, both in a wired or in a wireless fashion, I managed to 'see' the NAS.  Here is a ping to the NAS when my laptop is connected to the primary router:
[image: Ping from primary router to the NAS]
This proves that connectivity exists and that the IP Address assigned to the Seagate NAS is 192.168.0.198.  If I use this IP address in a browser, I can also see the configuration screen of the NAS.

However, when trying to ping the same IP from a laptop connected to the second router, connection times out:
[image: Pinging the NAS from a laptop connected to the second router]
Also, printing from this laptop is not successful.

Here is an ipconfig /all of the laptop that is connected to the second WiFi router:
[image: ipconfig /all of laptop connected to the second router]

I did not change the IP address of the second router because when I was changing it, it was freaking out, not letting me in the configuration settings neither with the old nor with the new IP.  I had to hard reset every time.

I hope this was not too long and that I gave enough info...

Thank you

Comment: Are you positive you have a link between the routers?  Are you using a cross-over cable between the routers?  To make an ethernet cross-over cable, you need to cut off one of the ends of the cable and swap the positions of leads 1 and 3, as well as 2 and 6.

Comment: Oh nevermind, you're able to get to the internet from the second one, so there must be a good link between the routers.